# What could be causing "collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status" when manually compiling C++ with pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, g++, pybind11

I have a C++ script which compiles with pybind11 to create a file that python can use.  I got it to work on my Ubuntu machine with python 3.8, but when I try to do it on my Windows machine it fails with `collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`.

From the research that I've done, the issue is that the g++ compiler can't find the include and library paths.  So I manually found the `Python.h` file in the `Python311\include` folder and set it to a variable in my `cmd` prompt.  I also found the `python3.lib` file and set that var in my windows `cmd` prompt.  I did the same for my pybind11 include path and all other include paths that I need.

Here is what I did:

```
> set HASHMAP_INCLUDE=C:\path\to\other\headers\include
> set PYBIND11_INCLUDE=C:\path\to\pybind11_x64-windows\include
> set PYTHON_INCLUDE=C:\path\to\Python311\include
> set PYTHON_LIBS=C:\path\to\Python\Python311\libs
> g++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -I %HASHMAP_INCLUDE% -I %PYBIND11_INCLUDE% -I %PYTHON_INCLUDE% -L %PYTHON_LIBS% test.cpp -o test.cp311-win_amd64.pyd
```

This ensures all needed paths are included for compiling.

But it fails and outputs many lines that all say pretty much the same thing:
`...undefined reference to PyObject_GenericSetDict`

And the last line is:

`collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

What does it take to use pybind11 on windows that is so different from linux?

Edit:

Here are some lines of the error output.

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQgaUv6.o:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN8pybind116detail16add_class_methodERNS_6objectEPKcRKNS_12cpp_functionE[_ZN8pybind116detail16add_class_methodERNS_6objectEPKcRKNS_12cpp_functionE]+0x8b): undefined reference to `__imp_PyGILState_Check'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQgaUv6.o:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN8pybind116detail16add_class_methodERNS_6objectEPKcRKNS_12cpp_functionE[_ZN8pybind116detail16add_class_methodERNS_6objectEPKcRKNS_12cpp_functionE]+0xd4): undefined reference to `__imp_PyObject_SetAttr'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQgaUv6.o:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN8pybind116detail16add_class_methodERNS_6objectEPKcRKNS_12cpp_functionE[_ZN8pybind116detail16add_class_methodERNS_6objectEPKcRKNS_12cpp_functionE]+0x164): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQgaUv6.o:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN8pybind116detail16add_class_methodERNS_6objectEPKcRKNS_12cpp_functionE[_ZN8pybind116detail16add_class_methodERNS_6objectEPKcRKNS_12cpp_functionE]+0x195): undefined reference to `__imp_PyObject_SetAttrString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQgaUv6.o:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN8pybind116detail16add_class_methodERNS_6objectEPKcRKNS_12cpp_functionE[_ZN8pybind116detail16add_class_methodERNS_6objectEPKcRKNS_12cpp_functionE]+0x1c5): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_Dealloc'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQgaUv6.o:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN8pybind116class_I4TestJEE3defIMS1_FvvEJEEERS2_PKcOT_DpRKT0_[_ZN8pybind116class_I4TestJEE3defIMS1_FvvEJEEERS2_PKcOT_DpRKT0_]+0x1b): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQgaUv6.o:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN8pybind116class_I4TestJEE3defIMS1_FvvEJEEERS2_PKcOT_DpRKT0_[_ZN8pybind116class_I4TestJEE3defIMS1_FvvEJEEERS2_PKcOT_DpRKT0_]+0x3c): undefined reference to `__imp_PyGILState_Check'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQgaUv6.o:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN8pybind116class_I4TestJEE3defIMS1_FvvEJEEERS2_PKcOT_DpRKT0_[_ZN8pybind116class_I4TestJEE3defIMS1_FvvEJEEERS2_PKcOT_DpRKT0_]+0x5b): undefined reference to `__imp_PyObject_GetAttrString'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQgaUv6.o:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN8pybind116class_I4TestJEE3defIMS1_FvvEJEEERS2_PKcOT_DpRKT0_[_ZN8pybind116class_I4TestJEE3defIMS1_FvvEJEEERS2_PKcOT_DpRKT0_]+0x17d): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_Dealloc'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQgaUv6.o:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN8pybind116class_I4TestJEE3defIMS1_FvvEJEEERS2_PKcOT_DpRKT0_[_ZN8pybind116class_I4TestJEE3defIMS1_FvvEJEEERS2_PKcOT_DpRKT0_]+0x18d): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_Dealloc'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQgaUv6.o:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN8pybind116class_I4TestJEE3defIMS1_FvvEJEEERS2_PKcOT_DpRKT0_[_ZN8pybind116class_I4TestJEE3defIMS1_FvvEJEEERS2_PKcOT_DpRKT0_]+0x19d): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_Dealloc'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQgaUv6.o:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN8pybind116class_I4TestJEE3defIMS1_FvvEJEEERS2_PKcOT_DpRKT0_[_ZN8pybind116class_I4TestJEE3defIMS1_FvvEJEEERS2_PKcOT_DpRKT0_]+0x1aa): undefined reference to `__imp_PyErr_Clear'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQgaUv6.o:test.cpp:(.data$_ZZN8pybind116detail25enable_dynamic_attributesEP15_heaptypeobjectE6getset[_ZZN8pybind116detail25enable_dynamic_attributesEP15_heaptypeobjectE6getset]+0x8): undefined reference to `PyObject_GenericGetDict'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQgaUv6.o:test.cpp:(.data$_ZZN8pybind116detail25enable_dynamic_attributesEP15_heaptypeobjectE6getset[_ZZN8pybind116detail25enable_dynamic_attributesEP15_heaptypeobjectE6getset]+0x10): undefined reference to `PyObject_GenericSetDict'
```

It seems like pybind11 is trying to use Python.h methods and failing to find them. For example, the `PyObject_GenericSetDict` is part of the `object.h` header file in the \Python311\include folder, which is the same folder that the `Python.h` file sits.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The meaning of `collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status` is "there was an error; see above". Ignore this message and focus on the real error.

Comment: Just guessing, but it looks like you've provided the path to a directory where Python libraries may be found, but have not specified the actual library you want.

Comment: @jkb i don't know what you mean, but I believe the -L flag looks for .lib files.  And when I do a search for all .lib files in Python311 folder, it only returns the ones that I have a path for.

Comment: I believe `-L` tells the linker to search a particular directory for library files, but it does not say to load every library in that directory. Try adding something like `-lpython3` to the command line. This is just off the top of my head, so the actual name of the library may be incorrect.

Comment: @jkb I get the same result when I include `-lpython3` or any variation of it, like `lpython311` `lpython3.11` `lpython3.11m` `lpython311m` etc.

Comment: What's interesting is that I just ran a python program that is supposed to output the python lib directory:  `import sysconfig; sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBDIR');` and it returned `None`.  Maybe my python installation was currupted... I originally install 3.12 but switched to 3.11.  Although i don't see how this would matter if my `Python.h` file and `python3.lib` file is manually pointed to by the compiler...

Comment: I would expect `-lpython3` (or maybe `-lpython311`) to work, assuming the path to the directory is correct. Does the path have spaces, and if so is it properly quoted/escaped?

Comment: @jkb I put the paths in quotes and still same error.